# Disagreeing 3-phase power

Tags: three-phase

So this feels like a silly one but I'm absolutely stuck. I'm trying to balance the power between a 3 phase source and two 3 phase loads in parallel. One is a Wye and the other is a Delta:
[image: layout]
So I figured out that the single phase source current is 5A per branch, so the source complex power is (3*120V*5A) = 1800 W and 0 var.

The problem comes when I try to find the load draw. It's easy enough to find the delta line-to-line voltage and the current going through the phases of the loads:
[image: V and I calcs]

When I go to sum the powers, though (including line impedance), I get a strange answer that doesn't balance:
[image: power calc]

Does someone see my obvious mistake?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, answered my own question. My line impedance power calc should have been 3*I^2*Z.